# Is it possible to list open SysV queues on certain files?

Tags: linux, system-v

I have a suite of applications that communicate with each other using SysV queues. However, when I stop the application there are sometimes queues left open, which in turn causes problems next time I start the application.

To resolve this I want to delete the queues left open, but to know which queues to delete I would like to be able to list which queues are associated with a specific file. Is this possible to do?

The queue is created using the following (simplified) code:

```c
    key_t key;
    int q_id;

    key = ftok("/some/file/name", 42);
    q_id = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
```

So by associated with a file a mean the path used in the `ftok` call.

Comment: what do you mean by 'associated with a specific file' ?

Comment: added further explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet, is to write a program that calls ftok, in order to obtain the key, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned long long key;
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage %s: [path] [id]\n" ,argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    key = ftok(argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));
    printf("%llx\n", key);
    return 0;
}
```

Once you have this key, you can use it to remove the message queue: `ipcrm -Q <key>`. Alternatively, you can modify the program above to call `msgctl(3)` to remove the message queue.

Comment: Nice and simple. I think I'll use this in a script to clean up the queues. Thanks :)